# How do I deserialize an object when its class is stored in an external jar?

Tags: java, serialization, classloader

I implement `Serializable` to save objects, like so:

```
public class MyType implements Serializable {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "This is a MyType";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("objecturl");
            outStream.writeObject(new MyType());
            outStream.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

I run that program once so a `MyType` is saved at `objecturl`.

Then, I package that one-class library up into a jar at `jarurl`.

If I want to use the object I saved in a new program, how can I give access to `MyType` to my new program, given the jar that contains `MyType.class`?

---

In otherwords, how can I use the jar at `jarurl` to allow the following to work without getting a `ClassNotFoundException`?

```
public class NewProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("objecturl");
            Object o = inStream.readObject();
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

where the output would be "This is a MyType", and `MyType` is not included in the same library as `NewProgram`.

---

Obviously there are other ways to get a program to output "This is a MyType". My major concern here is the usage of serialized, overridden implementation.

I know this has [something to do with ClassLoaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime/60775#60775), but I'm not sure how it works in this setting, where the type of the class is completely unknown, but the class's parent is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this myself but from some googling it seems there are two stages to the problem.

1. Create a ClassLoader that can load the class in question.
2. Create (or find an existing in a third party library) a subclass of ObjectInputStream that overrides the resolveClass method to use your ClassLoader rather than the automatically selected one. Use the subclass of ObjectInputStream to read your file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#resolveClass%28java.io.ObjectStreamClass%29

Comment: I was just arriving to this conclusion myself. So step 1 can be solved with the answer I linked, and step 2 I simply read that documentation to solve.